# How to configure select highlight colour in windows terminal

Tags: windows-10, themes, windows-terminal

I have been using windows terminal since quite a bit now. I am wondering if there is a way to change/configure the highlight colour. Currently it is `whitish grey`

In dark theme, it is very vivid as shown below
[image: Dracula Theme]

But in light theme, it is very difficult to track or differentiate it with background

[image: AtomOneLight Theme]

I am not able to use light themes properly because of this. Is there an option to change it or we have to live with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the `settings.json` file, normally found in
`%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\settings.json`. The easiest way to edit it is to click the down-arrow menu on the
title bar and choose `Settings`.

The setting you search is called `selectionBackground` and is in the format of
`#RRGGBB` (hex values for red, green, blue).
For example,
to change the selection background color for all profiles to red, add this line:

```
"profiles":
{
  "defaults": {
    // Put settings here that you want to apply to all profiles.
    "selectionBackground": "#FF0000"
  },
```

Other settings that might interest are the
`background` and `foreground` colors, of the same format.